# What does the notation $2^{\Omega}$ mean?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading about probability spaces, and several times I've seen statements along the lines of "define the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ to be $2^{\Omega}$."

My question is,

What does $2^{\Omega}$ mean? Is it just the power set of the sample space $\Omega$, or what?

Comment: The power set of $\Omega$. The notation comes from the fact that, for finite sets, $|P(A)| = 2^{|A|}$.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm curious, is there a $1.5^{\Omega}$ as well? Would this mean that $1^{\Omega} = \Omega$?

Comment: No such thing. Only 2 ever appears in the literature.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: That's not entirely true. In some contexts, $A^B$ would mean the set of functions from $B$ to $A$. (Which sometimes is also denoted by ${}^BA$.) In topological context, $2^X$ sometimes means the hyperspace of closed or compact subsets of $X$. Still, I haven't heard of anything like $1.5^\omega$ in any context at all.

Comment: @tomasz This is why I love MSE. Learn something new every day

Comment: @eepperly16: I believe the motivation goes quite a bit further than mere cardinality (see Mirko's answer).

Comment: @eepperly16 it is not just for finite sets, it is true for all sets empty, finite or infinite, that $|P(A)|=|2^A|=2^{|A|}$ where $2=\{0,1\}$ and $2^A$ is the set of all functions from $A$ into $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @eepperly16: You're welcome. But now I have deleted the longer comment, as I see that Mirko has posted an answer to just that effect. :)

Comment: @Tomasz but vacuum cannot exist so I immediately added a comment ;) (for the record, your comment indicated that we deal with functions into $\{0,1\}$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general $X^Y$ is the set of all functions from $Y$ into $X$. The number $2$ is understood as the set of all smaller non-negative integers (ordinals), thus $2=\{0,1\}$. Thus, $2^{\Omega}= \{0,1\}^{\Omega}$ is the set of all characteristic functions of subsets of $\Omega$, which is naturally identified with the power set $\mathcal P(\Omega)$. Namely, if $A\subseteq\Omega$ then $A$ could be identified with the corresponding characteristic function $\chi_A$ defined as $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$, and $\chi_A(x)=0$ if $x\in\Omega\setminus A$. This gives a natural correspondence (which is easily seen to be a bijection) between $\mathcal P(\Omega)=\{A:A\subseteq\Omega\}$ and $\{0,1\}^{\Omega}=\{f:f$ is a function with domain $\Omega$ into $\{0,1\}\}$.

Comment: This is very interesting info. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome ... though your question and my answer should be considered duplicate, as I just found after a search, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1115770 See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Representing_subsets_as_functions